# Structured Light scanner - camera calibration problem

Tags: python, opencv, scanning, 3dcamera

I want to create a 3D scanner based on structural light. How can i calibrate projector with camera in Python?

Hardware: Raspberry Pi 4, Pi Camera, Raspberry Pi HQ lens
Software: Python, OpenCV, and [this project](https://github.com/nkumarrai/Structured-Light)

Comment: why device or api are you using with the projector?

Comment: Raspberry Pi 4, Python and OpenCV. Im using this project: https://github.com/nkumarrai/Structured-Light

Comment: add that to your question

Comment: try editing the photos and see what editing they need

Comment: Edited, thanks ( its my first post on stackoverflow )

Comment: welcome. please take the [tour] and review [ask] and [mre].